# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration [custom configuration]

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Please, I'm working on converting a gradle 2.1 project to 6.0, but I get this error.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':driver'.
> Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: classesDirs.
 The following types/formats are supported:
   - A String or CharSequence path, for example 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'.
   - A String or CharSequence URI, for example 'file:/usr/include'.
   - A File instance.
   - A Path instance.
   - A Directory instance.
   - A RegularFile instance.
   - A URI or URL instance.
```

When running

```
configurations.driver.each {File file ->
    loader.addURL(file.toURL())
}
```

driver is a custom configuration define as

```
configurations {
    driver
}

dependencies {
    driver 'org.drizzle.jdbc:drizzle-jdbc:1.3'
}
```

Please any ideas how to fix?

Comment: It works for me with Gradle 6.0. Are you trying to loop over anything else than the "driver" configuration?

Comment: No, nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using

```
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.java.outputDir
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.test.java.outputDir
```

Instead of

```
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir= sourceSets.test.output.classesDirs
```